# .py files not opening in IDLE from OSX Finder?

Tags: python, python-2.7, osx-mountain-lion, python-idle, finder

I recently re-installed Python 2.7.3 from python.org on OSX 10.8.2, and now nothing (literally nothing I can see) happens when I double-click on .py files in Finder, or when I right-click/Open-With/IDLE(2.7.3).  (**Edit:** IDLE is already set as the default program to open .py files; the "right-click" part was just to illustrate I couldn't open them either way.)

I have Tcl/Tk 8.5.13 installed (re-installed after I re-installed Python), and I can open IDLE itself just fine, so this isn't that issue where IDLE won't work without the right version of Tcl/Tk.  I can also open .py files from the Terminal using `idle -e file.py` without a problem.

I did notice that the Python Launcher activates when I open files this way, and is absent when I double-click on .py files in Finder (although again, literally nothing happens when I do this--I have the IDLE icon in my dock and it doesn't start bouncing or anything).  Could this be a Python Launcher problem?  If not, does anyone know what's going on here?

**Update:** I tried opening IDLE first and then double-clicking on .py files, and that works.  So it seems it's just an issue of IDLE not being opened when you try to open a .py file in the Finder.

I know that means I now have at least three other ways of opening my .py files in IDLE, but I really like just being able to navigate to a file in Finder and open it when IDLE itself is not yet open.  So I'd still really like to solve this problem if possible (also I really hate when stuff that's just supposed to work doesn't).

**Update:** Per Ned Deily's suggestion I checked for errors using Console.app and found:

```
3/8/13 10:42:38.006 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[276]: ([0x0-0x199199].org.python.IDLE[1975]) Exited with code: 1
```

pops up whenever I try to double-click a `.py` file in Finder.

Comment: On any `.py` file: Right click -> Get Info and ensure that the default "Opens with" application is set to IDLE

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, thanks, yes, the default "Opens with" application is already set to IDLE...I guess I should have mentioned that but it seemed a bit basic.

Comment: Are you sure it's set to the _right_ IDLE? Once you've got multiple Python installations on your machine, it's very hard to distinguish them from within Finder…

Comment: @abarnert, thanks and noted, I did Right-click > Get Info and "changed" the default application by browsing to the IDLE sitting in my brand-new, python.org-installed Python 2.7 Applications folder, and nothing changed.  I think it was already set to the right IDLE anyway, since it said IDLE(2.7.3) and I had already removed all previous python.org Python installations.

Comment: I've just tested this with Apple's pre-installed Python (2.7.2), IDLE, and Tk (8.5.9) and it works. If you've been installing and uninstalling multiple versions of third-party Python, Tk, etc., it may be simplest to try to repro it on a clean machine by installing things one at a time until it breaks (or doesn't, in which case you now have a fix…), instead of trying to guess what you might have set up wrong in all those steps?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set the intended instance of `IDLE` as the default application for all `.py` files.  One way to do so is to select a `.py` file in a Finder window, then select the `Finder -> File -> Get Info` menu item (or `Cmd-I`).  In the `Open with:` section, pull down the application menu item and select the desired `IDLE`; if you have multiple copies of `IDLE` installed, select the `Other..` menu item at the bottom of the list and use the file chooser to select the right version of `IDLE`.  Then, click the `Change all...` button to `Use this application to open all documents like this one`.  You should now be able to launch a `.py` file in the desired IDLE by double-clicking.  If this doesn't work, examine `system.log` to see if there are any error messages being logged.  You can use the `Console` utility to examine logs (`/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`).

Comment: Thanks for answering; the method you described for setting the default IDLE used to open `.py` files is exactly what I've already tried.  It does appear there's an error being logged in the console each time I try to double-click a `.py` file in Finder: `3/8/13 10:42:38.006 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[276]: ([0x0-0x199199].org.python.IDLE[1975]) Exited with code: 1` So it looks like IDLE is starting up and then crashing?

Comment: Likely IDLE is finding some bad preference.  Try renaming or deleting your `~/.idlerc` directory.

Comment: Thanks, I renamed .idlerc and no effect on double-clicking `.py` files (although it did make IDLE nice and ugly when I then opened it directly).  Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of any reason why a given IDLE would fail without more detailed errors when implicitly launched (as a result of double-clicking an associated file) and not fail when the app itself is double-clicked. I don't recall any prior reports of such behavior. The only things I can suggest at the moment are to (1) consider cleaning your Launch Services data as suggested here (http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2013/02/getting-rid-of-open-with-duplicates/) and (2) if you feel ambitious, attempt to debug the IDLE.app startup by adding print statements etc.